# Which Redis commands does Sidekiq use?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, sidekiq

So, I renamed several dangerous Redis commands in redis.conf, after that Sidekiq WEB UI stopped showing any statistics yet Sidekiq is functioning fine. My question is which Redis commands does Sidekiq use? Which should I specify are renamed when configuring server and client inside Sidekiq initializer?

Comment: What ringed a bell is this line in sidekiq.log file:
`2019-07-31T08:38:01.654Z 3856 TID-goikyelz8 ERROR: heartbeat: ERR unknown command 'del'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no canonical list but the current Sidekiq supports Redis 2.8 so none of the newer commands in 3.0+.